# My segue bounces when I transition swift and I want it to be fluid

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]I have this segue here and it works fine, but when it does segue from one view to another it does this bouncing effect I dont want. Does anyone know how to fix it. I am transitioning from the back button to the trivia tab. How can I go back without losing the tab bar and having a transition go from left to right. Thank you.

```swift
let storyBoard UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
        resultViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.3
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        transition.type = .push
        transition.subtype = .fromLeft
        self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        self.show(resultViewController, sender: nil)
```

Comment: The problem is that that is not how to do a custom transition animation. I've seen that sort of thing a lot, yes, but it's wrong and you need to not do that.

Comment: can you guide me on the right way to do a transition? I still need it to be a push

Comment: Well, it's confusing: you are using `self.show` but you have no navigation controller? Why is that? I mean yes, I can tell you how to make the new view come in from the left, but it will not be a true push — it will be a _presented_ view controller.

Comment: I have a tabbar, will it disappear when I use the presented.

Comment: The problem is that you are asking the question so badly. Instead of showing us the wrong solution and asking what is wrong with it, tell us exactly what the _problem_ really is. What is the situation (the entire view hierarchy) and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Okay! So the simplest solution would be to use a UINavigationController with a hidden nav bar. That way, you could do what you want with almost no code at all.

Comment: I have to code it because sometimes I want the begin button to be a back button and I hide the back button below

Comment: What I'm saying is you don't need to code a fake transition animation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a fake transition to do this. You are trying to code something that looks and behaves like a navigation controller push; so you should *use* a navigation controller push. I was able to achieve your desired interface with no fake transition at all — in fact, my demo contains only one line of code:

[image]

That's a tab bar controller, containing a navigation controller, containing your first view controller, pushing to your second view controller. The navigation bar itself is hidden.

Comment: hey matt, i just have a few questions. What is the one line of code you use and how do you connect the segues